# Java WatchService and file system polling

Tags: java, performance, file, filesystems

The Java trail on [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) states that

> This API is not designed for indexing a hard drive. Most file system
>   implementations have native support for file change notification. The
>   Watch Service API takes advantage of this support where available.
>   However, when a file system does not support this mechanism, the Watch
>   Service will poll the file system, waiting for events.

My question :

If the directory watched is *not* the root directory (some subdirectory), and the file system does not support I/O event notifications, thus the `WatchService` implementation is polling the file system, does this polling slow down the entire system or just the listening application?

Or, in other words, considering a file system that requires the service to perform polling to detect changes, is there some threshold (directory depth, amount of files, etc.) where using this technique becomes an issue in terms of system performance (start to significantly affect OS performance) ?

**Note** : I understand that monitoring highly changing directories will affect the application *busyness* of responding to events and requiring even more CPU, regardless of the file system polling of not. I am more interested into monitoring a system data folder (ie. the user's Document directory, for example.)

Comment: As with general file system / OS operation: file system is basically sequential - i.e. any operation on file system must wait for previous operations to complete before completing itself. Basing on that **ANY** type of polling on file system **WILL** slow everything down. The effect will depend on FS usage not just by this process, but by other programs and system itself.